# Калькулятор для решений матрицы выводит ошибку в print

Tags: python-3.x

Код:

```
a1 = 3
a2 = -2
b1 = 1
b2 = 4
a1b2 = a1 * b2
a2b1 = a2 * b1
itog = a1b2 + a2b1
print(a1'*'b2'-'a2'*'b1'='a1b2'+'a2b1'='itog)
```

Ошибка:

```
 print(a1'*'b2'-'a2'*'b1'='a1b2'+'a2b1'='itog)
          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: При выводе должны быть запятые между аргументами print (между именами переменных и строками в данном случае)

Comment: Или плюсы для конкатенации строки.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, для конкатенации строк - да, но тут строки и числа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a1'*'` это синтаксическая ошибка. Питон разрешает объединять только константы без дополнительных операторов: `'x' 'y' == 'xy'`.

Чтобы поместить значение переменной внутрь строки, можно `f''` строки использовать в Питоне 3.6+:

```
print(f'{a1}*{b2}+{a2}*{b1}={a1b2}+{a2b1}={itog}')
```

Или не вводя дополнительных переменных:

```
print(f'{a1}*{b2}+{a2}*{b1}={a1*b2}+{a2*b1}={a1*b2+a2*b1}')
```

Чтобы сделать равенства верными, я дополнительно заменил минус на плюс.

Оба `print()` вызова выводят:

```
3*4+-2*1=12+-2=10
```

Питон 3.5 не поддерживает `f''`-строки, можно явно `''.format` метод вызвать:

```
print('{a1}*{b2}+{a2}*{b1}={a1b2}+{a2b1}={itog}'.format(**vars()))
```

Comment: Интересное решения проблемы,но проблема осталась та же

Comment: Либо вы не точно скопировали код либо вы не используете Python 3.6

Comment: http://prikolol.16mb.com/123.png

Comment: и какая версия Питона у вас? `python -V`

Comment: Версия 3,5 python

Comment: Добавил вариант для Питон 3.5